# How to Parameter the size of Camera

Tags: android, android-camera

Hi
I'm working in the android application that use camera to take picture of barcode,the camera works fine, and it takes pictures,but I want to parameter the size of camera to be able to take picture with size of barcode, so if you have any idea , please help me
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since you can only use a limited range of preview and picture sizes, depending on which sizes are available to the device's camera, the ideal is to have one of the available sizes and then crop the captured image so that it fits to the barcode's size and then eventually resize the picture to the device's screen size.

You need to be able to detect the barcode with some algorithm which you might have implemented already in your application, and then crop it.

You can then scale the resulting bitmap object by using the method from the Bitmap class:

```
createScaledBitmap(Bitmap src, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, boolean filter)
```

Comment: I didn't implement the detection barcode algorithm, I just implement the algorithm that decode the barcode, have you any idea of how can I detect the barcode, thanks

Comment: There are algorithms available around the web for barcode detection. For the Android case, one of the most popular Android Image Processing Libraries called JJIL, has a specific part dedicated to barcode detection. You can find more information about it at this link: http://code.google.com/p/jjil/wiki/FindingTheBarcode